# VBA vs PowerAutomate protecting sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365

I had an excel files with 3 sheets Password protected in order to prevent data insertion in the cells out of the range I needed.
I wrote a VBA script to let the user have a button to add a line to a Table and insert data in the (new) Table range only and a second button to cancel a line from the Table. In this way, I was sure that any user will not insert any data out of the Table.

Now I have to run this file online on Microsoft 365, which do not allow VBA to run in online app version.
I tried to check Power Automate, but I fount nothing similar to the script I needed.

This in my script:

```
Sub NewLine()
'
' Nuova Linea in Tabella Attività
'
Dim oTabella As ListObject
Dim lastrow As Long
Const miaTabella As String = "Attivita"
Const miaPassword As String = "123456789"
    With ActiveSheet
        Set oTabella = .ListObjects(miaTabella)
        .Unprotect Password:=miaPassword
        oTabella.ListRows.Add
        
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A").Value = "=TODAY()"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

        .Protect Password:=miaPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    End With
End Sub


Sub DeleteRow()
'
' Cancella Linea in Tabella Attività
'
Const miaPassword As String = "123456789"
    With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:=miaPassword
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        .Protect Password:=miaPassword, Contents:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Note: it's not a problem for my to have "password in clear", because the only thing I want is to prevent data insertion out of the Table, so it's not a security issue from my side.

How can I block data insertion out from the Table if not using VBA?

Thank in advance

Comment: Although Excel has online version, it's not fully functional. I don't think there is a good way to achieve what you need. I think sharepoint list would be a better option for you.

Comment: You would have to be using TypeScript and the Office-JS library in Excel Online. Found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nsakar/bfbf14263245c7daf50dce8eb44e9381) with a quick Google search, should help get you started.